# how to do import `take` in javascript for RxJS 6 now?

Tags: import, rxjs6

Looks like imports are clearer in typescript for RxJS 6 now but in javascript how to import `take` operator?

Tried with

```
import 'rxjs/operators/take';
```

Also tried with ES6:

```
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

but did not work. Complains that take is not a function.

Comment: `import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';`? There are plenty of examples in the docs, e.g. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md#build-your-own-operators-easily

Comment: Are you sure you read the question - it was asking how to do import in JAVASCRIPT now. And I mentioned from the beginning that imports are clearer in typescript for RxJS 6. Yes, import { take } from 'rxjs/operators'; is typescript import...

Comment: That *is* JavaScript, if you're using es6 imports. If not please specify.

Comment: Yes, This syntax is ES6 javascript, but take is not imported. still complains that take is not a function.

Comment: Then please [edit] the question to give a [mcve] *of that*. Show the import you're using and the traceback; *"did not work"* isn't a particularly helpful problem statement.

Comment: Thanks. I have added the offered solution to the tries. Also made it clear that the node.js complains that take is not a function.

Answer (score 7):

First install rxjs lib: `npm i rxjs`

then use it like:

```
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import {take} from 'rxjs/operators';

fromEvent(domElement, 'some-custom-event').pipe(take(1)).subscribe((ev) => {
            console.log("value=", ev)
        });
```